# How to use a class in another class

Tags: php, oop

I have one "master class" called User. Basically all it does is initialize the username with __construct(). I've created a separate group called "Groups". The groups class will allow me to retrieve the "groups" a user belongs to. For example:

```
public function getGroups($username) {
    return $usersgroups; // there's much more to this, obviously.
}

$groups = new Groups();
$usergroups = getGroups("admin");
```

But instead, can I just use my user class and do something like the following?:

```
$user = new User("admin");
$user->groups->getGroups();
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Starting reading about OO design. :)

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you've realized we should be able to get the user's groups from an instance of `User` is good.

On the most basic level, you should really have a `setGroup` and `getGroups` method. You may even include another method called `setGroups` that adds an array of `Group` instances (or a `GroupCollection`).

To get you on the right path, you probably want to do something like:

```
class Users {

    protected $groups = array();

    public function __construct ()
    {

        // ...

    }

    public function setGroup ( Group $group )
    {

        array_push( $this->groups, $group ); // may require private addGroup method depending on how complex the registration is
    }

    public function getGroups ()
    {

        return $this->groups;

    }

}
```

You'll notice I'm using a method `setGroup` and `getGroups`. Like I said above, you could include another method called `setGroups`. It's a bit more complicated, but basically what you'd need is another whole class called a `GroupCollection`, which is essentially a glorified array of `Groups`. That'd look something like:

```
class Users {

    protected $groups;

    public function __construct ()
    {

        $this->groups = new GroupCollection;

    }

    public function setGroups ( GroupCollection $groupCollection )
    {

        $this->groups = $groupCollection;

    }

    public function addGroups ( GroupCollection $groupCollection )
    {

        $this->group->merge( $groupCollection );

    }

    public function addGroup ( Group $group )
    {

        $this->groups->addGroup ( $group );

    }

    public function getGroups ()
    {

        return $this->groups; //returns a GroupCollection

    }

}
```

You can get pretty detailed with this stuff -- it all depends on what you're trying to do and how complicated it is. Above I'm using more advanced domain objects, but if you're just starting off, I'd suggest reading more into OOP. I gave you a few examples to show how in depth you can get with these objects, and feel free to play around and ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just initialize the `$groups` member variable in the constructor of User.  You can refererence it as `$this->groups` in any method in the class.